# Visual Basic 2013 How to Ping all IPs in ListBox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, listbox

Hello this is my first time posting here. well to the point, I have pieced together 
a app that is able to load a text file, add on the fly to a "listbox", now all i need it to Ping all ips in said "listbox" but i get an error and stops working. need help to ping all ips.

```
Private Sub Go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Go.Click




    If ListBox1.Items.Count <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please Add at Least One IP or Website!")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    For l_index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1        'THIS IS WHERE CODE STOPS WORKING, NEED "MAGIC CODE" HERE
        Dim lines As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(l_index))
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lines)
    Next





End Sub
```

I am using Openfiledialog to load Text File to listbox1 and backgroundworker to do the ping. I am using

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
```

What i want to do is once that all "IPs" are in the listbox i want to press Go to Ping all Ips. How can i get this to work?

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO

Public Class Main


Private Sub AboutUpingToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutUpingToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AboutUping.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub MenuStrip1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles MainMenu.ItemClicked

End Sub

Private Sub QuitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()

End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Create.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



End Sub


Private Sub Go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Go.Click

    If ListBox1.Items.Count <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please Add at Least One IP or Website!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For l_index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1        'THIS IS WHERE CODE STOPS WORKING, NEED "MAGIC CODE" HERE
        Dim lines As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(l_index))
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lines)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CloseFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdADD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdADD.Click
    Dim myitem
    myitem = txtADD.Text()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(myitem)
    txtADD.Clear()





End Sub

Private Sub cmdRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRemove.Click
    For a As Int32 = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

        For i As Int32 = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            '-- compare the value of the select item to any given item in the list.

            If ListBox1.SelectedItems(a) = ListBox1.Items(i) Then

                '-- remove the item by the index we found

                ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)

                '-- exit the inner for loop

                Exit For

            End If

        Next

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdClear.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub HelpToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HelpToolStripMenuItem.Click

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim lines = DirectCast(e.Argument, String())
    Dim Ping As New Ping
    Dim replies As New List(Of PingReply)

    For Each ip In lines
        Dim reply = Ping.Send(ip)
        replies.Add(reply)
    Next

    e.Result = replies
End Sub
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim replies = DirectCast(e.Result, List(Of PingReply))

    For Each reply In replies
        Dim index As Integer
        index += 1

        sb.Append("Ping ").Append(index).Append(": ").Append(reply.Address).Append("                   ").Append(reply.RoundtripTime).Append(" ms")
        sb.AppendLine()
    Next

    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by stop working? any exception? crash? or data error?

Comment: Yes the app crashes and i get an error that says:
Targetinvocationexception was unhandled by user code
followed by "An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: What i want to do is once that all "IPs" are in the listbox i want to press Go to Ping all Ips. How can i get this to work?

Comment: Are you updating the result of ping from BackgroundWorker1? could you share the code for do work for the same. I think i know where is the issue.

Comment: Sure i will add all code

Comment: Code is Up. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: You can generally ignore the `TargetInvocationException`... more importantly, what is the inner `Exception` that you are getting?

Comment: i am Getting this
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Uping.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String[]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!Got it to work! Sending "Listbox1" to array

```
Private Sub Go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Go.Click

    Dim lines() As String = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)().ToArray()

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lines)



End Sub
```

Now it works app does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here

one of your ping fails and results an exception which is returned to the completed event handler and when the handler tries to get the result the TargetInvocationException exception is thrown

solution is to check the error

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim replies = DirectCast(e.Result, List(Of PingReply))

        For Each reply In replies
            Dim index As Integer
            index += 1

            sb.Append("Ping ").Append(index).Append(": ").Append(reply.Address).Append("                   ").Append(reply.RoundtripTime).Append(" ms")
            sb.AppendLine()
        Next

        TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
    Else
        'error handling
    End If
End Sub
```

additionally you may need to handle the actual error to protect rest of the ping replies otherwise because of 1 failure whole batch of result will be lost

```
For Each ip As String In lines
    Try
        Dim reply As PingReply = Ping.Send(ip)
        replies.Add(reply)
    Catch ex as PingException
        'error handling
    End Try
Next
```

**Update**

another point of error,

```
For l_index As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1        
    Dim lines As String = CStr(ListBox1.Items(l_index))
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lines)
Next
```

since you are passing as single string from the method above and in the method below you are attempting to cast as string array so it fails, change it like this

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim ip = DirectCast(e.Argument, String)
    Dim Ping As New Ping
    Dim replies As New List(Of PingReply)

    Try
        Dim reply As PingReply = Ping.Send(ip)
        replies.Add(reply)
    Catch ex as PingException
        'error handling
    End Try
    e.Result = replies
End Sub
```

also advised to use Option Strict On to reduce some type checking errors

Comment: Nope this did not fix it... The error is happening @ BackgroundWorker1_doWork
Dim lines = DirectCast(e.Argument, String())  -- is the exact line where it breaks.

Comment: i didn't go that deep, perhaps you may also wrap that piece of code in try catch block. also try to see the data why the error occurs.

Comment: there was error in casting, updated my answer also dont forget to apply previous answer as it will still be valid for invalid or unreachable hosts.

Comment: Got it to work sending "listbox1" to Array. Thank You Very Much.